# Theory of finding the Mode of a key

Tags: guitar, theory

Finding the notes of G Phrygian.
The ‘Phrygian Mode, is the third mode along from the Ionian, Major - 
of which major scale is G the 3rd note?". 
The answer is E flat major. 
So, G Phrygian has the same notes as E flat major, but, starting on the 3rd note (G). 
( G Ab Bb C D Eb F G )...

Is this correct?

Parent Major Scale ?

Time to test yourself...

It's really important that you guys test yourself.
Here are some Q'and A's, to get you started...

1. What is the PMS for G  Dorian?
2. What is the PMS for C#  Phrygian?
3. What is the PMS for B Locrian?
4. What is the PMS for E Mixolydian?
5. What is the PMS for A# Mixolydian?
6. What is the PMS for D Aeolian?
7. What is the PMS for Bb Dorian?
8. What is the PMS for Ab Lydian?
9. What is the PMS for G# Dorian?
10. What is the PMS for Eb Mixolydian?
    Answers...
11. F Maj - 2. A Maj - 3. C Maj - 4. A Maj - 5. D# Maj -
12. F Maj - 7. Ab Maj - 8. Eb Maj - 9. F# Maj - 10. Ab Maj.

Comment: there is already an answer to this https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/77049

Comment: and this one https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/75881

Answer (score 4):

This can be a matter of preference, but it may be easier to get the notes of a given mode by knowing the alterations to either a major or minor scale.

Phrygian is (like) a minor scale with a lowered ^2 degree.

So G minor uses a `Bb` and an `Eb`, just add the lowered ^2 `Ab` to get the `G` Phrygian mode.

Comment: I agree, the first thing that came to my mind was this other approach, which I think is more appropriate and simpler, in general...

Comment: @coconochao, an additional thought: the way most seem to get introduced to modes - permutating the modes of the major scale - sort of leaves a sense of plain diatonic sound. It's like a big melodic sequence of the major scale. When you keep a tonic fixed and then add the accidentals to create all the modes I think you get a better sense of the darkening/lightening character of each mode.

Comment: It can help when people talk about 'the Phrygian' for example in regard to "Phrygian cadence' or the Neapolitan chord has a 'Phrygian' color, or why people talk about the Mixolydian in a blues context, etc. Those involve an alteration of the key or scale where the tonic is fixed, not a permutation of the scale.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's the way it works. Take, for instance, G Dorian. Dorian is based on the second note of the major scale, so that scale is F. Therefore G Dorian has Bb in it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add another possible way of getting there.

I like to think of modes in the C major scale, maybe because I can very easily picture it on a keyboard. So, thinking of Phrygian, I would think of the scale beginning on E, then I would either:

- look at the intervals (S-T-T-T....) and apply them starting at G;
- compare it with E minor scale (it's almost the same thing, but with F instead of F#) and conclude the same as Michael Curtis: "Phrygian is a minor scale with a lowered ^2 degree." Then apply the lowered 2 degree to G minor.